# Query Strings with React for a small weather app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jquery-selectors, web-development-server

I want to be able to set a city for my weather app using query-strings like ?latt_long=34.052235,-118.243683&&woeid=2442047. Here is a link to it https://github.com/rushingMarina/weather-react-app .  Right now I have a cities.json file in my project and App.js fetches data about the cities from there. I can not seem to figure out how to use query-strings. On https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string it tells me to use const queryString = require('query-string'); in order to use query-strings but I can not declare a const in my App.js.

My App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import FrontSide from "./FrontSide";
import BackSide from "./BackSide";
import "./panel.css";
import cities from "./cities.json"
import queryString from 'query-string';


class App extends Component {

const queryString = require('query-string'); //I get unexpected token error (11:6) on this line right before queryString
console.log(location.search);

state = {flipped: false, currentCity: cities[0]};


 onFlip =() => {
    this.setState({flipped: !this.state.flipped});
 };

 onSelectCity = (city) => {
   this.setState({currentCity: city})
 }


  render() {
    return (
        <div className={`panel ${this.state.flipped ? 'flip' : ""}`}>
            <div className="panel-front">
            <FrontSide onClick={this.onFlip} currentCity={this.state.currentCity}/>
          </div>
            <div className="panel-back">
            <BackSide
              cities={cities}
              onClick={this.onFlip}
              currentCity={this.state.currentCity}
              onSelect={this.onSelectCity}
              />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
  }
}

export default App;
```

My cities.json

```
[
  {
    "title":"Los Angeles",
   "location_type":"City",
   "woeid":2442047,
   "latt_long":"34.052235,-118.243683"
  },
  {
  "title":"San Diego",
  "location_type":"City",
  "woeid":2487889,
  "latt_long":"32.715736,-117.161087"
  },
  {
  "title":"New York",
  "location_type":"City",
  "woeid":2459115,
  "latt_long":"40.730610,-73.935242"
  },
  {
  "title":"Chicago",
  "location_type":"City",
  "woeid":2459115,
  "latt_long":"41.881832,-87.623177"
  },

  {"title":"St Petersburg",
   "location_type":"City",
   "woeid":2123260,
   "latt_long":"59.932739,30.306721"
  }

]
```

i tried declaring 
          const queryString = require('query-string');
but react shows unexpected token at "queryString"

Please refer to my github link, there you will find App.js and cities.json files

I expect to get information about the city to display on my FrontSide from URL query-string like.

This is the error I am getting:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/App.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token (11:6)

   9 | class App extends Component {
  10 |
> 11 | const queryString = require('query-string');
     |       ^
  12 | console.log(location.search);
  13 |
  14 | state = {flipped: false, currentCity: cities[0]};
```

Comment: Please post your code here, not behind an external link.

Comment: @ColinRicardo sure :)

Comment: did you try `import queryString from 'query-string'`. And as I know, this module is a `NodeJS` module, not for React.

Comment: Yep, it might be a good idea to try use the `qs` module.

Comment: @dqlgnoleht  I am trying to use queryString but I am not sure why I can't declare const queryString in my App.js

Comment: answer of Patrick. H is the right one for you

Answer (score 1):

Just remote the `const queryString = require('query-string');` line out of the class declaration and put it on top. Just right below the import statements and everything should work fine. React doesn't like require statements inside the class declaration